# SCSS: Assign border-radius based on element size

Tags: css, sass, border-radius

I am setting a rounded border using this `.rounded` class

```
.rounded {
  border-radius: 1rem !important;
}
```

The border looks good most of the time

[image]

But on small elements, it does not looks very good.

[image]

---

Is there any way, using scss that I can set the border radius so that on wider elements, it would be `1rem` but on smaller elements, it would be `0.5rem` or something, so that the search bar looks about the same but the square looks more like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, please do not use `!important` this is a sign you have not control about your selectors.

Second, you could you percentage value instead for the absolute one.
For expample `border-radio: 25%`

Comment: Percentages didn't create the same effect, I'll upload an example. I'm using important because I'm overriding a bootstrap class, and I'm pretty sure bootstrap uses `!important` on this class